# javascript сортировка option и value по алфавиту

Tags: javascript

На странице есть списки например

```
<select multiple="multiple">
    <option value="2" selected="selected">С отделкой</option>
    <option value="3">Без отделки</option>
</select>

<select multiple="multiple">
    <option value="2" selected="selected">Банан</option>
    <option value="3">Абрикос</option>
<option value="4">Зелень</option>
</select>
```

Как выстроить эти списки по алфавиту(с сохранением value и selected у option) при загрузке страницы, чтобы получалось так

```
<select multiple="multiple">
    <option value="3">Без отделки</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">С отделкой</option>
</select>

<select multiple="multiple">
    <option value="3">Абрикос</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">Банан</option>
    <option value="4">Зелень</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Такие вещи надо сортировать перед выводом и не надо тогда будет костыль выдумывать!

Answer (score 1):

```js
function sortOptions(select) {
  var items = [...select.querySelectorAll("option")];
  items.sort((a, b) => a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1);
  items.forEach(item => select.appendChild(item));
}
```

```html
<select multiple="multiple" id="produce">
  <option value="2" selected="selected">Банан</option>
  <option value="3">Абрикос</option>
  <option value="4">Зелень</option>
</select>

<br/>
<button onclick="sortOptions(document.getElementById('produce'))">Sort</button>
```